# Moz website and Chrome toolbar show inconsistent values for my site's page and domain authority

Tags: seo-audit, domain-authority

My site page authority (PA) is 3 and domain authority (DA) is 9 on Moz bar Chrome extension.

On their website, PA is 1 and DA is also 1.

Which one is more accurate?

Comment: This is indeed strange and looks like a bug from Moz. Have you tried contacting Moz directly about this issue?

Comment: No i have not contacted moz. But the increase was recent.

Comment: One thing I could think of, is that the toolbar might use a different and/or cdn'ed version of their database displaying older data. But even then, a jump from DA 1 to DA 9 is, in fact, not very reassuring...

Comment: I think the chrome extensions tends to update faster. What do you think?

Comment: @Oliverkahn:  Are you using their paid version?  They have stopped updating the index database, of their free version.  Maybe this is where the inconsistency is coming from?

Comment: @Craig its the free version am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few weeks ago, Moz announced that they were no longer updating the index database, for their Free Keyword Tool 'Open Site Explorer'.  For purposes of clarity, the index database, is where all SEO related metrics are stored.  Metrics, such as:

- Backlinks
- Anchor Texts
- SERPs
- Linking Domains

... to name some of the very few basic metrics.

By no longer updating such metrics, the Tool retains the last 'score' you achieved, up until the last day they updated their index database.

Unlike the Open Site Explorer, their Google Chrome Extension, is being updating on an ongoing basis.  As such, the Chrome Extension is likely to provide you with a more up to date 'score', rather than an 'archived score'.

It is for this reason, it is likely you are seeing an inconsistency in your 'SEO Scores'.